# TCL file not found by NS2 in MAC OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, tcl, ns2

I have just installed NS2 on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)

I have set all the paths correctly.

I can successfully type '**ns**' on the terminal, and '**nam**' as well, and both execute without any problem.

The problem is that when I input a file to the ns command, it says:

`couldn't read file "example.tcl": no such file or directory`

I use this command in the terminal:

`ns example.tcl`

I also tried it running it in sudo mode:

1. `sudo -s`
2. `ns example.tcl`

I placed the file in the bin folder, where there's ns's shortcut, I also placed it where actually the ns is. I also tried giving it a full path to the tcl file, but no use in both the cases.

I also tried to run it after executing only ns first, and then within ns ran it (No idea if it works like this, I am just trying everything I have got!)

1. `ns`
2. `%ns example.tcl` (Hash sign shows the NS is running and I am typing the command there)

This time the error is:

`warning: using backward compatibility mode`

`error when calling class OldSim: hello-ddos.tcl`

The version of NS is 2.35.

**NOTE:** I changed the file extension from `.tcl` to `.txt`, and it works fine now. Any idea of the problem?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
couldn't read file "example.tcl": no such file or directory
```

is pretty clear. It simply couldn't find the file; the OS returned an ENOENT error from the underlying system call to open the file. The usual reason for this is that the file isn't in the directory that you're running the program from, and the usual recommendation for dealing with this is to **use the *full* name of the file** instead of just the local path-less version. (It's technically possible for there to be other issues, but they usually produce different errors.)

What can cause this? Well, one of the most common things is if you (or some library code, such as what is inside NS2) does a `cd` to change the current directory. Using a full, absolute filename makes (or at least *should* make) your code much more resistant to that sort of thing.

---

Warning: note that the second part of your question relating to changing the filename is strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory of your file. It should be in the bin folder inside your ns folder.
Also you may try typing 
    `sudo ./ns filename.tcl`
to give you root access if by any chance you are detached from that.